# Visual Studio C# OleDB WinForms Combobox Databinding issue

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox, oledb

So my problem is that my combobox wont work right. I will explain my steps

My combobox is Databinded to a table from a database with only the Value Member set to None
When i start the program and select something from the combobox every txtbox and button seems blocked. Can't edit txtboxes and buttons do nothing.

If i assign a Value Member all txtboxes and buttons work perfectly. But the list when selecting the combobox changes its values after selecting a value.

My code:

```
    private void getData()
    {
        // fetch data from the database
        con.Open();
        if (cBoxBox.Text != "")
        {
            string syntax = "Select X, Y, Z, Content from AutoStoreDBTable where BoxNumber =@BoxNumber";
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(syntax, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BoxNumber", string.Format(cBoxBox.Text));
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                txtBoxXcoord.Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                txtBoxYcoord.Text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                txtBoxZcoord.Text = dr.GetValue(2).ToString();
                txtBoxContent.Text = dr.GetValue(3).ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you explain, in broad terms, what you're trying to do? Knowing what your overall goal is will help us better understand your specific issue.

Comment: Hello. My goal is to fill 4 textboxes with values depending on what is chosen from the combobox.The combobox is binded to a table so when for example a name is selected in the combobox the code will search the table and fill the txtboxes with the right address, surname and gender binded to that name in the table. I also want that the list that appears when selecting the combobox stays the way it is. Right now the list is ordered from 1 to 24. But when i select a number that number will take the place of 1. And 1 will dissapear.